# Error "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" al utilizar SQL a través de Python

Tags: python, sql

Tengo un problema y quisiera ver si me pueden ayudar a resolverlo. Estoy trabajando en SQL a través de Python con la siguiente tabla, que contiene llave primaria y llaves foráneas que se vinculan con otras tablas del proyecto:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
  | comic_id |   descripcion   | autor_id | editorial_id |
----------------------------------------------------------
1 |     1    | X-MEN #2 - 1995 |    1     |       1      | 
----------------------------------------------------------
2 |     2    | Spiderman-1990  |    1     |       1      |
----------------------------------------------------------
3 |     3    |  Superman-2011  |    2     |       2      |
----------------------------------------------------------
4 |     4    |  Batman A1-2020 |    3     |       3      |
----------------------------------------------------------
5 |     5    |  Batman A3-2020 |    3     |       3      | 
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Desde mi archivo principal ¨main.py¨, mi idea es seleccionar por nombre, buscando palabras clave de la columna "descripción". Para ello, este archivo contiene el siguiente código:

```
from src.dao.comic_dao import *

comic_buscar = input("Ingrese nombre a buscar: ")

comics = ComicDAO.seleccionar_por_nombre(comic_buscar)
for comic in comics:
    log.debug(comic)
```

El archivo principal importa el contenido del archivo "comic_dao.py", el cual contiene el siguiente código:

```
from src.dao.conexion import Conexion
from src.entities.comic import Comic
from src.logger_base import log

class ComicDAO:
    '''
    DAO (Data Access Object)
    CRUD (Create-Read-Update-Delete)
    '''
    # _SELECCIONAR = 'SELECT * FROM comic ORDER BY comic_id'
    _SELECCIONAR_POR_NOMBRE = 'SELECT * FROM comic'
    # _INSERTAR = 'INSERT INTO comic(descripcion) VALUES(%s)'
    # _ACTUALIZAR = 'UPDATE comic SET descripcion=%s WHERE comic_id=%s'
    # _ELIMINAR = 'DELETE FROM comic WHERE comic_id=%s'

    # @classmethod
    # def seleccionar(cls):
    #     with Conexion.obtenerConexion() as conexion:
    #         with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
    #             cursor.execute(cls._SELECCIONAR)
    #             registros = cursor.fetchall()
    #             comics = []
    #             for registro in registros:
    #                 comic = Comic(registro[0], registro[1], registro[2], registro[3])
    #                 comics.append(comic)
    #             return comics

    @classmethod
    def seleccionar_por_nombre(cls):
        with Conexion.obtenerConexion() as conexion:
            with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(cls._SELECCIONAR_POR_NOMBRE)
                registros = cursor.fetchall()
                comics = []
                for registro in registros:
                    comic = Comic(registro[0], registro[1], registro[2], registro[3])
                    comics.append(comic)
                return comics

    # @classmethod
    # def insertar(cls, comic):
    #     with Conexion.obtenerConexion() as conexion:
    #         with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
    #             valores = (comic.descripcion)
    #             cursor.execute(cls._INSERTAR, valores)
    #             log.debug(f'Comic insertado: {comic}')
    #             return cursor.rowcount

    # @classmethod
    # def actualizar(cls, comic):
    #     with Conexion.obtenerConexion():
    #         with Conexion.obtenerCursor() as cursor:
    #             valores = (comic.comic_id, comic.descripcion, comic.autor_id, comic.editorial_id)
    #             cursor.execute(cls._ACTUALIZAR, valores)
    #             log.debug(f'Comic actualizado: {comic}')
    #             return cursor.rowcount

    # @classmethod
    # def eliminar(cls, comic):
    #     with Conexion.obtenerConexion():
    #         with Conexion.obtenerCursor() as cursor:
    #             valores = (comic.comic_id,)
    #             cursor.execute(cls._ELIMINAR, valores)
    #             log.debug(f'Objeto eliminado: {comic}')
    #             return cursor.rowcount

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Insertar un registro
    # comic1 = Comic(descripcion='Spiderman-1990')
    # comics_insertados = ComicDAO.insertar(comic1)
    # log.debug(f'Comics insertados: {comics_insertados}')

    # Actualizar un registro
    # comic1 = Comic(1, 'Spiderman-1990', 1, 1)
    # comics_actualizados = ComicDAO.actualizar(comic1)
    # log.debug(f'Comics actualizados: {comics_actualizados}')

    # Eliminar un registro
    # comic1 = Comic(comic_id=1)
    # comics_eliminados = ComicDAO.eliminar(comic1)
    # log.debug(f'Comics eliminados: {comics_eliminados}')

    # Seleccionar objetos
    comics = ComicDAO.seleccionar()
    for comic in comics:
        log.debug(comic)
```

Este archivo a su vez, importa el contenido de tres archivos más. Estos son:

- "comic.py" con el siguiente código:

```
from src.logger_base import log

class Comic:
    def __init__(self, comic_id=None, descripcion=None, autor_id=None, editorial_id=None):
        self._comic_id = comic_id
        self._descripcion = descripcion
        self._autor_id = autor_id
        self._editorial_id = editorial_id

    def __str__(self):
        return f'''
            Comic Id: {self._comic_id}, Descripcion: {self._descripcion},
            Autor Id: {self._autor_id}, Editorial Id: {self._editorial_id}
        '''
    @property
    def comic_id(self):
        return self._comic_id

    @comic_id.setter
    def comic_id(self, comic_id):
        self._comic_id = comic_id

    @property
    def descripcion(self):
        return self._descripcion

    @descripcion.setter
    def descripcion(self, descripcion):
        self._descripcion = descripcion

    @property
    def autor_id(self):
        return self._autor_id

    @autor_id.setter
    def autor_id(self, autor_id):
        self._autor_id = autor_id

    @property
    def editorial_id(self):
        return self._editorial_id

    @editorial_id.setter
    def editorial_id(self, editorial_id):
        self._editorial_id = editorial_id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    comic1 = Comic(1, 'X-MEN #2 - 1995', 1, 1)
    log.debug(comic1)
    # Simular un insert
    comic1 = Comic(descripcion='X-MEN #2 - 1995')
    log.debug(comic1)
    # Simular un delete
    comic1 = Comic(comic_id=1)
    log.debug(comic1)
```

- "conexion.py" con el siguiente código:

```
from src.logger_base import log
import psycopg2 as bd
import sys

class Conexion:
    _DATABASE = 'comics'
    _USERNAME = 'postgres'
    _PASSWORD = 'admin'
    _DB_PORT = '5432'
    _HOST = '127.8.8.1'
    _conexion = None
    _cursor = None

    @classmethod
    def obtenerConexion(cls):
        if cls._conexion is None:
            try:
                cls._conexion = bd.connect(host=cls._HOST,
                                           user=cls._USERNAME,
                                           password=cls._PASSWORD,
                                           port=cls._DB_PORT,
                                           database=cls._DATABASE)
                log.debug(f'Conexión exitosa: {cls._conexion}')
                return cls._conexion
            except Exception as e:
                log.debug(f'Ocurrió una excepción {e}')
                sys.exit()
        else:
            return cls._conexion

    @classmethod
    def obtenerCursor(cls):
        if cls._cursor is None:
            try:
                cls._cursor = cls.obtenerConexion().cursor()
                log.debug(f'Se abrió correctamente el cursor: {cls._cursor}')
                return cls._cursor
            except Exception as e:
                log.error(f'Ocurrió una excepción al obtener el cursor: {e}')
                sys.exit()
        else:
            return cls._cursor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Conexion.obtenerConexion()
    Conexion.obtenerCursor()
```

- "logger_base.py" con el siguiente código:

```
import logging as log

log.basicConfig(level=log.DEBUG,
                format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s',
                datefmt='%I:%M:%S %p',
                handlers=[
                    log.FileHandler('capa_datos.log'),
                    log.StreamHandler()
                ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log.debug('Mensaje a nivel debug')
    log.info('Mensaje a nivel info')
    log.warning('Mensaje a nivel de warning')
    log.error('Mensaje a nivel de error')
    log.critical('Mensaje a nivel critico')
```

Al ejecutar con Pycharm el archivo "main.py" me da como resultado el siguiente error:

```
C:\Python\python.exe 
main.py
Ingrese nombre a buscar: Spiderman
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sabina\Documents\Juan\Archivos\Juan\2022\Trabajos\Github\Comics\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    comics = ComicDAO.seleccionar_por_nombre(comic_buscar)
TypeError: ComicDAO.seleccionar_por_nombre() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Quisiera saber si alguien podría ayudarme con este código para que ejecute correctamente, ya que no le encuentro la forma.
Para más información, este proyecto se encuentra en el siguiente repositorio con su respectiva descripción:

```
https://github.com/jpiro80/comics
```

Muchas gracias.

---

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Hice algunas modificaciones y obtuve resultado sin errores, aunque todavía no logré el objetivo:

- En el archivo "comic_dao.py" en:

```
def seleccionar_por_nombre(cls)
```

agregué:

```
def seleccionar_por_nombre(cls, comic_buscar)
```

El resultado obtenido al ejecutar fue el siguiente:

```
03:28:23 PM: DEBUG [conexion.py:23] Conexión exitosa: <connection object at 0x0000017954F417A0; dsn: 'user=postgres password=xxx dbname=comics host=127.8.8.1 port=5432', closed: 0>
03:28:23 PM: DEBUG [main.py:7] 
            Comic Id: 1, Descripcion: X-MEN #2 - 1995,
            Autor Id: 1, Editorial Id: 1
        
03:28:23 PM: DEBUG [main.py:7] 
            Comic Id: 2, Descripcion: Spiderman-1990,
            Autor Id: 1, Editorial Id: 1
        
03:28:23 PM: DEBUG [main.py:7] 
            Comic Id: 3, Descripcion: Superman-2011,
            Autor Id: 2, Editorial Id: 2
        
03:28:23 PM: DEBUG [main.py:7] 
            Comic Id: 4, Descripcion: Batman A1-2020,
            Autor Id: 3, Editorial Id: 3
        
03:28:23 PM: DEBUG [main.py:7] 
            Comic Id: 5, Descripcion: Batman A3-2020,
            Autor Id: 3, Editorial Id: 3
        

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Es decir, el listado completo de la tabla, aunque lo que debo conseguir es que en el resultado sólo aparezca la lista de elementos de la palabra clave que yo escribo cuando me dice: ""Ingrese nombre a buscar: "
Eso es lo que me faltaría. Tenés idea de cómo lograrlo?
Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

El método `seleccionar_por_nombre` es un método estátic0 (o de clase). Su primer argumento es la clase

```
def seleccionar_por_nombre(cls):
```

La forma correcta de ejecutarlo es

```
ComicDAO.seleccionar_por_nombre()
```

o sea, sin parámetros, pues `cls` es un parámetro *implicito*. Su valor es la clase donde está definido (`ComicDAO`) el método:

```
class ComicDAO:
    @classmethod
    def seleccionar_por_nombre(cls):
        print(cls)

x = ComicDAO.seleccionar_por_nombre()
```

produce:

```
<class '__main__.ComicDAO'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Si le pasas un argumento más, se produce el error mencionado:

```
x = ComicDAO.seleccionar_por_nombre("Juan")
```

produce:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raul/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 6, in <module>
    x = ComicDAO.seleccionar_por_nombre("Juan")
TypeError: seleccionar_por_nombre() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Por otra parte, mirando el cuerpo del método, verás que `cls` no se ocupa por ninguna parte, por lo que no tiene sentido pasarle nada en la llamada.

Ahora, si quieres pasarle un parámetro, debes declararlo así:

```
def seleccionar_por_nombre(cls, a_buscar):
```

para luego ocuparlo dentro del cuerpo.

Comment: Ahí hice una respuesta, pero no sé si te llega porque es como que me la respondí a mi propio posteo. Espero que la puedas ver. Gracias!

Comment: @jpiro80. Felicitaciones!, pero mejor haz una nueva pregunta para analizarla mejor. Me parece que "seleccionar_por_nombre" debería ser simplemente una función.

Answer (score -1):

El metodo `seleccionar_por_nombre` es un metodo de clase, el parametro cls es la misma clase y se introduce de manera automatica, tu estás introduciendo 1 parametro, por lo que en total son 2 pero el metodo solo acepta 1(la misma clase)

Comment: Por ejemplo, al ejecutar main.py aparece el input "Ingrese comic a buscar" Y ahí se debe escribir una palabra clave, por ejemplo "X-MEN" y la idea es que al hacerlo aparezcan listados solamente los comics que contengan la palabra "X-MEN". Eso sería lo que no sé cómo lograr. Muchas gracias